# ASP.NET download speed throttling

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have been trying to find the best way to throttle downloads from my site.

On my site I have several large downloads. What I want to do is limit the total bandwidth that can be used for downloading files so that the experience of others users is never impacted.

For example:

I have a 100Mb/s connection. I want to ensure that 30Mb is always reserved for serving pages.

I want file downloads to never exceed 70Mb/s.

Those figures are cumulative for all users.

I am aware that I can set the value for the entire server using

```
SiteLimits.MaxBandwidth
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.sitelimits.maxbandwidth?view=iis-dotnet

I can also set a single download using

```
Stream throttledStream = new ThrottledStream(Response.OutputStream, 1024);
```

Comment: Create a separate app on the server for downloads, then use `SiteLimits.MaxBandwidth` appropriately.

Comment: I did think about that but Im also using user authentication

Comment: You could implement a simple sso system. Or use an expiring token.